# How do I ignore the created column on a Zend_DB table save?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

how would I ignore having Zend_DB save() from trying to fill out a created column? I do not need that column for a certain model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't send the data. `save()` is part of the `Zend_Db_Table_Row` api and is designed to be somewhat intelligent in the way it saves data to a row. It will perform an insert or an update of a row depending on what is required.

`save()` will also only update the columns that it has data for. If you don't send new data for your created column `save()` won't overwrite the data.

When ever it is possible I let the database I'm using create and update the columns for created and updated. That way I have the information available to query if I need it but I don't have to do something with PHP that My database can do better.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html Section "Advanced usage".

> For more specific and optimized requests, you may wish to limit the
>   number of columns returned in a row or rowset. This can be achieved by
>   passing a FROM clause to the select object. The first argument in the
>   FROM clause is identical to that of a Zend_Db_Select object with the
>   addition of being able to pass an instance of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
>   and have it automatically determine the table name.
>
> **Important**
>
> The rowset contains rows that are still 'valid' - they simply contain
>   a subset of the columns of a table. If a save() method is called on a
>   partial row then only the fields available will be modified.

So, if you called an update() I think it would be as simple as unsetting the value for the column you don't want to touch.  Of course database constraints will need to be honored -  i.e. column should allow nulls.